# HTML File Only Reads Style Attributes Within Elements

Tags: html, css

**EDIT: Three days ago my site was perfect and I didn't update any of the css or html.**

A few days ago I noticed that my website's style was not being displayed as it should be. It's almost as though the browser overrode my stylesheet and displayed everything inline in Times New Roman. (I checked my website in Chrome and IE)

When I try to style a particular html element in my stylesheet, the browser won't read it. But when I style it within the html it does.

You might say that the html document isn't reading the css file properly, but the funny thing is that some of the elements are being read like the header, navigation bar and footer.

**HTML Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new-site.css" media="screen"/> 
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300|Open+Sans:400,700|Roboto:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <?php include('includes/googleAnalytics.php'); ?>
    <?php include('includes/nav.php'); ?>
        <div id="content-custom">
            <div id="main-custom">
                <div id="main-intro-custom">
                <br>
                <br>
                <span>Contact Us</span>
                <p>Questions or comments? Send us a message. We would love to hear from you.</p>
                </div><!--end mainintrocustom-->
            </div><!--end main-custom-->
            <div id="contact">
                    <div id="checkfaq">
                    <a href="faq.php">Check our FAQ to see if your question has been answered.</a>
                    </div><!--end checkfaq-->
                    <form name="contact" method="post">
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" required/>
                    <br><br>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" required/>
                    <br><br>
                    <textarea name="message" placeholder="message" required></textarea>
                    <br><br>
                    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" />
                    </form> 

</div><!--end contact-->    
        </div><!--end content-->
    <?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
</div><!-end wrap-->
</body>
</html>
```

Take this page for example, the only elements that aren't styled are the ones within `<div id="contact">`.

If I write

```
#contact{
background:orange;
}
```

in the external stylesheet, the browser won't display it.

But when I add this:

```
<div id="contact" style="background:orange;">
```

The browser displays it.

The weirdest part of all is that I never changed a single thing in the CSS nor in the HTML. I contacted hostgator to see if it was something on their end and they told me it's not a server error.

**How can I fix this mess? Has anyone else encountered this problem.**

**EDIT: Here's a link to my stylesheet:** [CSS HERE](https://imprintnation.net/new-site.css)

**EDIT: I think the problem was that I didn't close `.imgThumb:hover`. Why did it take a couple of days for the browser to screw up the layout while I was testing? And why were other pages affected by this mistake if this class `.imgThumb` is not included in those pages?**

Comment: The problem is in the part of the page that was not disclosed or even alluded to the question, namely some *other* external style sheet linked to. Well, it could also be a problem with *your* external style sheet (e.g., wrong URL). You should post a minimal example that actually reproduces the problem. E.g., omit PHP code unless you have checked that it actually affects the issue, and if it does, show the HTML code sent to browsers rather than PHP instructions.

Comment: The html I posted is the actual page that is having this problem.

Comment: What you included is PHP, not HTML. And it includes no reference to any stylesheet. There are 22 errors and several warnings reported by http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ if you submit your CSS URL to it (but we don’t even know whether browsers actually read it. Check it again: could you reconstruct the problem (create a page where it occures) from *only* the information given in the question?

Comment: I edited the code and it shows everything inside the `head` section, including the link to the stylesheet. I have passed my stylesheet through a validator and the errors it points to are the CSS3 attributes found in my stylesheet. And like I said before, this page is giving me the problem. Every html element EXCEPT `<div id="contact">`and the child elements within it, are being styled by the stylesheet.

Comment: The validator says that I'm using CSS2 and that the CSS3 attributes are errors. How can I fix that?

Comment: First thing, you didn't close your `.imgThumb:hover` selector in the css file. Second, it seems a very specific problem, so why won't you create a dummy page in your site with the same structure and css/js paths so we can look into it?

Comment: The question still contains PHP code, not an HTML document. The question does not include the CSS code at all. Both the HTML code and the CSS code fail to pass validators. The descriptions of the problem are inconsistent: the question itself says that everything is in Times New Roman, whereas a comment says that only one element is not styled.

Comment: @Gil I think closing that tag fixed it. Now my question is, why did it take so long for the browser to screw everything up? Why didn't the browser immediately tell me that something needed to be closed by screwing up the entire layout when I was testing it, instead of screwing up when the site went live?

Comment: @JosanIracheta My guess is that it did screw up the display but maybe you didn't catch it because of local cache in your browser(s). And since a missing `}` or the opposite `}}` "break" the rest of the css file, other pages that used this css didn't get their selectors as well.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that any one of your plugin(may be a wordpress) would have used !important to avoid overriding of style.

You can check this by inspecting the element using FireBug or dev tools.  If that the case then no other choice simply go for it

```
#contact{
background:orange !important;
}
```

Comment: I'm not using Wordpress. This is just my own html and css. I tried using `!important` and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You're running into a style priority collision with your CSS. From what I can gather, since you can apply inline styles successfully but not from a stylesheet, you probably have another style overriding the styles in your stylesheet. You can check this by opening Developer Tools in Chrome, inspecting the element, and viewing the Computed styles. If you expand the styles you're interested in, you should see which styles are overridden, as they are crossed out.

I don't recommend this since it can get out of hand, but in a pinch you can force your styles to be applied (assuming another stylesheet doesn't do the same) by adding an `!important` tag to them.

```
#contact {
    background:orange !important;
}
```

If you want to avoid this, you can use a more specific selector, which in CSS raises the priority of the style. If you can get this to work, I highly recommend using this approach instead, as it will lead to *much* less headache going forward with style changes:

```
.parentContainer #contact {
    background: orange !important;
}
```

The more specific you can be, the better. If you know the element's immediate parent, I would advise you use the selector `parentContainer > #contact`, which is more explicit than the previous one, which will simply detect any descendant, not just an immediate child node.

Comment: There are no styles overriding. I can confirm this by having tried adding `!important` with no success.